# How to tune a Machine Translation model with huge language model?

Tags: nlp, n-gram, machine-translation, moses, language-model

`Moses` is a software to build machine translation models. And `KenLM` is the defacto language model software that moses uses.

I have a textfile with 16GB of text and i use it to build a language model as such:

```
bin/lmplz -o 5 <text > text.arpa
```

The resulting file (`text.arpa`) is 38GB. Then I binarized the language model as such:

```
bin/build_binary text.arpa text.binary
```

And the binarized language model (`text.binary`) grows to 71GB.

In `moses`, after training the translation model, you should tune the weights of the model by using `MERT` algorithm. And this can simply be done with https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/training/mert-moses.pl.

MERT works fine with small language model but with the big language model, it takes quite some days to finish.

I did a google search and found KenLM's filter, which promises to filter the language model to a smaller size: https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/filter/

But i'm clueless as to how to make it work. The command help gives:

```
$ ~/moses/bin/filter
Usage: /home/alvas/moses/bin/filter mode [context] [phrase] [raw|arpa] [threads:m] [batch_size:m] (vocab|model):input_file output_file

copy mode just copies, but makes the format nicer for e.g. irstlm's broken
    parser.
single mode treats the entire input as a single sentence.
multiple mode filters to multiple sentences in parallel.  Each sentence is on
    a separate line.  A separate file is created for each sentence by appending
    the 0-indexed line number to the output file name.
union mode produces one filtered model that is the union of models created by
    multiple mode.

context means only the context (all but last word) has to pass the filter, but
    the entire n-gram is output.

phrase means that the vocabulary is actually tab-delimited phrases and that the
    phrases can generate the n-gram when assembled in arbitrary order and
    clipped.  Currently works with multiple or union mode.

The file format is set by [raw|arpa] with default arpa:
raw means space-separated tokens, optionally followed by a tab and arbitrary
    text.  This is useful for ngram count files.
arpa means the ARPA file format for n-gram language models.

threads:m sets m threads (default: conccurrency detected by boost)
batch_size:m sets the batch size for threading.  Expect memory usage from this
    of 2*threads*batch_size n-grams.

There are two inputs: vocabulary and model.  Either may be given as a file
    while the other is on stdin.  Specify the type given as a file using
    vocab: or model: before the file name.  

For ARPA format, the output must be seekable.  For raw format, it can be a
    stream i.e. /dev/stdout
```

But when I tried the following, it gets stuck and does nothing:

```
$ ~/moses/bin/filter union lm.en.binary lm.filter.binary
Assuming that lm.en.binary is a model file
Reading lm.en.binary
----5---10---15---20---25---30---35---40---45---50---55---60---65---70---75---80---85---90---95--100
```

**What should one do to the Language Model after binarization? Is there any other steps to manipulate large language models to reduce the
computing load when tuning?**

**What is the usual way to tune on a large LM file?**

**How to use KenLM's filter?**

(more details on https://www.mail-archive.com/moses-support@mit.edu/msg12089.html)

Comment: Are you sure it's the language model that makes MERT that slow? I'm quite new to SMT, but for some reason I would expect the size of the translation model to be more problematic. And this can be fixed with `training/filter-model-given-input.pl`.

Comment: Yes, it is the big language model that makes MERT slow. I've tried with various sizes of LM.

Answer (score 1):

Answering how to use `filter` command of [KenLM](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/)

```
cat small_vocabulary_one_word_per_line.txt \
  | filter single \
         "model:LM_large_vocab.arpa" \
          output_LM_small_vocab.
```

Note: that `single` can be replace with `union` or `copy`. Read more in the help which is printing if you run the `filter` binary without arguments.